# Can I refactor several similar properties

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have several classes which send out PropertyChanged when the values of their properties changes. I have a base class which derives from INotifyPropertyChanged and implements both the PropertyChanged event and the method OnPropertyChanged.

My other classes derives from this base class and then all their properties follow the same pattern: there's a class variable holding the value and a property which reads/sets this variable along with a call to OnPropertyChanged in the setter.

```
private int number = 42;
public int Number
{
    get { return number; }
    set { number = value; OnPropertyChanged("Number"); }
}
```

This code is starting to show up so much I am wondering if I can somehow refactor it to reduce the number of lines for each property. Or is it overkill to try to reduce these six lines of code (+3 lines of comment specification)?

Comment: This is in fact missing lines from the "correct" implementation of the pattern. A full implementation will include `if (number == value) return;`. Now that is out of the way, why do you care? This code is fast and can be collapsed down to one line by any half decent IDE. I say go on with life and worry about something more important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into some of the build-time tools for injecting propertychanged notification that are around, a quick google turned up https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged however it's not the one i've seen on projects from my company. Off the top of my head I can't remebmer which one they used.

Comment: This is only for Visual Studio, right? Unfortunately I use both it and Xamarin Studio (Mono) as IDEs. Perhaps I should just collapse the code and move on with my life, as you suggested. :P

Comment: @ChristofferBrodd-Reijer I suspect (i didn't check too deeply) that they inject things into the .csproj file, so as long as you are using an IDE that uses msbuild to run it's builds then you can likely use it in both although you will need to use visual studio to get any IDE integration it provides.